# Getting multiple items from eBay with Single item API shows ERROR

Tags: php, ebay-api

I'm using eBay **Single item API** to get details for selected items.
I know eBay have multiple-item API also but it will not give all the details I want.

---

I have a Var `$gpd` where I have item numbers. Then using `explode` to make Array `$items`

Then using `foreach` to run eBay Single item API for all items in Array.

Then added 20% profit and roundup the price.

Then making static PayPal button.

---

My code below works perfect mostly of the time. But sometimes it shows ONLY the 2 first items in Array and then shows the ERROR:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($response) or die("Error: Could not get item");
```

If I again reload the page then it shows all the items in Array and everything works perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$gpd = '281616878215, 221694130228, 191506118709, 271806308878, 231451119156' ;
$items = explode(', ', $gpd);
$profit = "1.2";
function round_up ($value, $places=0) {
  if ($places < 0) { $places = 0; }
  $mult = pow(10, $places);
  return ceil($value * $mult) / $mult;
}

foreach($items as $item) {
$appID = 'HERE-NEED-TO-PUT-EBAY-APPID';
$exexex = $item;
$request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <GetSingleItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" >
            <ItemID>'.$exexex.'</ItemID>
            <IncludeSelector>Details,ShippingCosts,ItemSpecifics,Variations</IncludeSelector>
            </GetSingleItemRequest>';
$callName = 'GetSingleItem';
$compatibilityLevel = 647;
$endpoint = "http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping";
$headers[] = "X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: $callName";
$headers[] = "X-EBAY-API-APP-ID: $appID";
$headers[] = "X-EBAY-API-VERSION: $compatibilityLevel";
$headers[] = "X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING: XML";
$headers[] = "X-EBAY-API-RESPONSE-ENCODING: XML";
$headers[] = "X-EBAY-API-SITE-ID: 0";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: text/xml";

$curl = curl_init($endpoint);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$data = simplexml_load_string($response) ;

$AckResponse = $data->Ack ;

$xml=simplexml_load_string($response) or die("Error: Could not get item");
$itemvalueprice = (float)$data->Item->ConvertedCurrentPrice;
$itemprice = $itemvalueprice * $profit;
$price = round_up ($itemprice, 1);
$paybutton = '<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"><input type="hidden" name="business" value="my@paypal.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="' . htmlentities($data->Item->Title, ENT_QUOTES) . '">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="' . $price . '"><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="IMEI"><input type="text" name="os0" >
<br />
<input type="image" src="ordernow.jpg" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
</form>' ;
$endt = str_replace(".000Z", "", $data->Item->EndTime);
$endtime = explode(T,$endt);
$startt = str_replace(".000Z", "", $data->Item->StartTime);
$starttime = explode(T,$startt);
$oldtrans = array('P','D','T','H','M','S');
$newtrans = array('<span class="red"> in </span>','d, ','','h ','m ','s');
$timeleft = str_replace($oldtrans,$newtrans,$data->Item->TimeLeft);


echo '<h2>' . htmlentities($data->Item->Title, ENT_QUOTES) . '</h2>
<span>Price <strong>' . $price . '</strong>$ </span>
<span>Sold <strong>' . $data->Item->QuantitySold . '</strong> </span>
<span>Score <strong>' . $data->Item->Seller-> PositiveFeedbackPercent . '</strong>% </span>
<span><strong>' . $data->Item->ListingStatus . '</strong></span>
<span><img src="' . $data->Item->GalleryURL . '" alt="' . htmlentities($data->Item->Title, ENT_QUOTES) . '" /></span>
<span>' . $paybutton . '</span><span>Expires ' . $endtime[0] . '' . $timeleft . '</span>
<br /><br />' ;
}
?>
```

My question is why does it show `ERROR`? If there is an `ERROR` why does it show all items most of the time? And even with `ERROR` it will always show the 2 first items in the array.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between GetSingle(Multiple)Items api call.

The GetMultipleItems api call can take 20 items at one go.

Try this:

```
$appid = YOUR_APPID;
$items = implode( ',', ITEM_ARRAY);

// much simpler than using curl
$xml = simplexml_load_file( "http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetMultipleItems&responseencoding=XML&appid=YOUR&siteid=0&version=897&ItemID=$items&IncludeSelector=Details");
```

You can get extra data by specifying the `IncludeSelector` parameter.

http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetMultipleItems.html#Request.IncludeSelector

Getting the `QuantitySold` for each item:

```
$ack = strtolower( ( string ) $xml->Ack );

if( $ack == 'success' ) {
    foreach( $xml->Item as $item ) {
        echo "ItemID - " . $item->ItemID . '<br />';
        echo "QuantitySold - " . $item->QuantitySold . '<br />';
        echo '<br /><br />';
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: in my script I do "foreach" to loop and then echo $data->Item->QuantitySold for every single item + add my info then again run it again. Your way is much better but how can I then split the items? how to do echo $data->Item->QuantitySold for item 1, 2, 3 so on..?

Comment: That solved my problem :-) Now using GetMultipleItems instead. Thank you for helping. Much better using simplexml_load_file instead of cURL